# Can Regulus Signolit self-adhesive films be used with a HP CP5225?

Tags: laser-printer, film

Some days ago I had luck and was able to buy a used HP CP5225dn for an unbelievable price. Actually, I didn't need an A3 color laser printer urgently, but I couldn't resist given the price and the condition of the device (in fact, it is nearly unused; although obviously having been built back in 2012, only about 8000 pages have been printed).

The person who sold me the device also donated me a pack of self-adhesive white films of type "Regulus Signolit SC 46 A3".

My question could not be simpler: Can I use those films with the HP CP5225 without damaging the printer?

The person who sold me the printer was not sure about this because he was in the process of liquidating a company which had many color laser and inkjet printers, and it was unclear which accessory / paper / film had been used with which printer.

Unfortunately, I could not find any information regarding this when I did my homework. HP does not seem to have a compatibility matrix of which films can be used with which printer, and Regulus / folex does not seem either.

I would be very grateful if somebody could tell me for sure (no guessing please; I really don't want to brick that device because "most" films will work, but that special one doesn't).

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

["SIGNOLIT ® SC 46 selbstklebende PET-Folie für Laser und Kopierer, weiß glänzend"](http://doc.officio.de/artikel/s/sc46_1.pdf)

My German is a little weak, but that seems to say that it's designed for use with laser printers and copiers.

Comment: native speaker here - `selbstklebende Polyesterfolie weiß glänzend für
  Farbkopierer und Farblaserdrucker` means "self-adhesive PET-film for laser and inkjet, glossy white". `Drucksysteme: Farblaserdrucker, Farbkopiergeräte` means "printing systems: laser printers, inkjet printers". **So: You are correct.**

Comment: @flolilolilo: Laser and inkjet need very different surface preparations regarding plastics. I would be surprised if it worked with both.

Comment: That's what it says. Although my translation is rough (as we're looking for specs, not a poem), "Farbkopierer" definitely is a generic term for ink jets. Also: what else would it be? Needle? ;-)

Comment: @flolilolilo Your first comment is correct, so +1 :-) But the manufacturer's website says: "For use on **most** Mono & Colour Laser Printers." (emphasis mine). So I am slightly mistrustful.

Comment: @flolilolilo: I find color copiers when I search for that word.

Comment: yes, you do. That's because it's a generic term. It could mean all forms of color printers, but since laser is already specified, it most certainly means ink jet, as "Drucker" or "Kopierer" mostly refers to ink jet-devices in German, i.e. you would also say "**Laser**drucker" if you want to state that it uses laser, while I never heard someone say "**Tintenstrahl**drucker" (if no clarification is necessary). Also, the only other option would be "needle printers" ("**Nadel**drucker"), but that seems unlikely. The sentence from the website is different from what the specs you posted above say.

Comment: @flolilolilo I don't think that "Farbkopierer" means ink jets. You are obviously young :). Formerly, the copiers were working like laser printers (mono as well as color). The "big" color copiers are still working like that. The all-in-one inkjet devices are quite new and more for SOHO usage.

Comment: @Binarus So why specify it twice? It would seem to me that just using the term "Drucker mit Laser" or "Geräte mit Laser" (or something similar) would be more exact in this case. *(However, I think I'm overruled here ;-) )*

Comment: @flolilolilo To make people sure about it. Most people do not know that the bigger copiers are working like laser printers. If you have already been in a copy shop, you probably remember that the paper was warm or even hot immediately after having left the copier ...

Comment: And the ozone... my goodness the ozone...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, the smell is an additional indication ...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for your answer and upvoted, but the manufacturer's website (which you could switch to English language :-)) says: For use on **most** Mono & Colour Laser Printers." (emphasis mine). So I am slightly mistrustful.

Comment: @Binarus: The thing is that some manufacturers (e.g. Brother) use a special toner formulation that may react poorly with some media. But HP uses essentially the same formulation across all its laser printers (with the main difference being the pigments, CMY vs. K) so if something claims compatibility with one of a manufacturer's class of machines then I'm inclined to believe that it will work across all their machines of that class.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams O.K., thanks, I think I'll just give it a try.